# TestCase properties access with TestRunner

Tags: jenkins, hudson, soapui

My testCases have custom properties defined as TestCase properties. When i launch the test in the SoapUI environment the properties value changes, but when i use the testrunner doesn't.

I have a "current" var containing the current user info to use in the testCase. Each time the TestCase executes the current var increases in one but when using the testrunner (in jenkins & soapui) it doesn't. The increase code is the following and it's saved in a Groovy Script contained in the testCase.

```
def i = context.testCase.getPropertyValue("_current");    
if(Integer.parseInt(i)+1 < Integer.parseInt(total)) {
    context.testCase.setPropertyValue("_current",String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(i)+1));    
    log.info("Current user "+testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("_current"));
    } else {
    context.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("_current","0");    
        log.info "###__!!! Reached limit of users !!!__###";
    }
```

I think the testRunner doesn't execute the groovy scripts contained in the testCase. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out

The TestCase and TestSuite properties are embedded in the XML project file. For the changes to persist save is needed. Just need to add the -S flag in the testrunner command.